# Using JPA Entity to persist HTTP Request

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-rest

I expose an endpoint where my client invoke requests to fire spring batch jobs.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private MyProcessor processor;

    @PostMapping(value = "/runJob", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<MyResponse> runJob(@Valid @RequestBody MyRequest request) {
        //persist the request using Spring JPA
        String requestTrackingId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        MyResponse response = processor.process(request, requestTrackingId); //run spring batch job and create response
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, CREATED);
    }

}
```

Requests include name, and some other params:

```
public class MyRequest {
    private String name;
    private String runDate;
    private boolean rerun;
}
```

I have a requirement to use Spring JPA to persist the http job run requests in a table. The table should persist the request data along with the unique id so it can be tracked and also should capture job status so it can be queried by clients using the tracking id.

I need help with the JPA implementation including creating the entity and persisting the request to the table when it hits the endpoint. What would the implementation look like? The id on the table should the tracking id.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Please give additional information if you want a more sophisticated answer.

One possible implementation:

**The Model**

```
    @Entity
    @Table
    public class RequestData{
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false, length = 32)
        private String id; // = IdGenerator.generateId(); #use it if you want to get the id from the object, and not set it.

        @Basic
        private String name;

        @Basic
        private String runDate;

        @Basic
        private Boolean rerun;

        //[getters/setters] here
    
    }
```

**Repository interface**

```
public interface RequestDataRepository extends JpaRepository<RequestData, String>{}
```

Now you can inject the repostiory to your controller and save the request:

```
    @Autowired
    private RequestDataRepository repository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/runJob", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<MyResponse> runJob(@Valid @RequestBody MyRequest request) {
        String uniqueId=IdGenerator.generateId()
        RequestData requestData=new RequestData();
        requestData.setId(uniqueId);     
        requestData.setName(request.getName())
        .... //other fields setters (except id)
        repository.save(requestData)
        //alternativelly get the id from the object, then you do not need to create id here, but in the RequestData object
        //String uniqueId=requestData.getId();
        [...]
    }
```

**UUID generator**

```
public final class IdGenerator {

        private static org.springframework.util.IdGenerator idGenerator = new AlternativeJdkIdGenerator();
    
        private IdGenerator() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("IdGenerator is an utility class");
        }
    
        public static String generateId() {
            return idGenerator.generateId().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you create UUID using UUID.randomUUID() and set it ? what is this way achieving ?

Comment: From the doc:
`An IdGenerator that uses SecureRandom for the initial seed and Random thereafter, instead of calling UUID.randomUUID() every time as JdkIdGenerator does. This provides a better balance between securely random ids and performance.`

Comment: you wanted an unique id as i understand the question: `request data along with the unique id `. UUID for the best to achieve this.

Comment: since I need it in the restcontroller class, can you update answer creating with UUID and setting to request object?

Comment: you can get it from the object, but i update it to you of course.